# Mapreduce - How to call manually call setup() / create Mapper.Context object?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce Mapper class as follows:

```
public class MyClassMapper extends Mapper<WritableComparable, ComboWritable,
    WritableComparable, WritableComparable> {
```

I need to utilize some of the methods in this class (not the MapReduce part). I would like to initiate MyClassMapper through its setup() method, which just does some private argument setting in MyClassMapper. Unfortunately, I cannot alter MyClassMapper.

```
MyClassMapper myClassMapper;
myClassMapper.setup(context);
...
Boolean myresult = myClassMapper.aMethodCall():
```

It looks like the setup() Method needs a Mapper.Context object.

```
Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT>.Context context
```

Is there a way to create a Context object?

Comment: Are you going to use this within Hadoop framework or outside of it ?

Comment: @Amit from inside the Hadoop framework.

I need to call myClassMapper.aMethodCall() from another mapreduce job.

Comment: To start with, is it really necessary in your case to call setup() before you call aMethodCall ? If so, have you tried passing the Context available to you in your mapreduce class to MyClassMapper ? .

Comment: @Amit it is necessary to call setup()

My issue is that I need to call this method in the reducer of my mapreduce class. So I have Reduce.Context - while setup() expects Mapper.Context. If there is a way to convert between the two context then that might also work.

Comment: In that case I think you probably should rethink what is the dependency of aMethodCall in a mapper on the Context object. If it makes sense you should create a Helper or Utility class that can be used both in Mapper and Reducer.